# Showing different content inside lightbox, before and after form has been submitted

Tags: jquery, html, css, mailchimp

I'm trying to create a "thank you" form URL with MailChimp.

Take a look [here](http://www.fantasylab.no/fantasylab) by clicking at the "Subscribe" button and filling out the form.

When a user has filled out the form and clicks "Submit", the content inside the lightbox should change and the lightbox itself should still be displaying, but right now the content and the lightbox itself doesn't display after you have submitted the form.

Also I need to send subscribers to another URL or else it will show the default "thank you" page, and under "General Forms" on MailChimp.com, I have added the website URL. I am not sure if that's causing the problem.

**my html**

```
<div id="1">
  <div id="demo-second">
    <div class="plainmodal-close-second"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div> <!-- end of plainmodal-close -->
    <h3 class="title">Subscribe to our newsletter</h3>
    <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </br>
      </br>
      <hr id="line-break">
      </br>
      </br>
    <div  class="container">
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
      <form action="//fantasylab.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=d1f6a8e82535d2fcc14bfa66f&amp;id=36a4ce5a35" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
      <div class="left-row">
            <div class="mc-field-group">
              <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME" placeholder="Fullt navn*">
            </div>

            <div class="mc-field-group">
              <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Din e-postadresse">
            </div>
      </div> <!-- end of left-row --> 
          <div class="right-row">
            <div class="mc-field-group">
              <input type="text" name="MMERGE2" class="" value="" id="mce-MMERGE2" placeholder="Telefonnummer">
            </div>

            <div class="mc-field-group">
              <input type="url" value="" name="TES" class=" url" id="mce-TES" placeholder="Din Webside">
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end of right-row -->           

          <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
          </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->

            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_d1f6a8e82535d2fcc14bfa66f_36a4ce5a35" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
            </div>
      </form> <!-- end of form -->
      </div>  <!-- end of mc_embed_signup -->
    </div> <!-- end of container --> 
 </div>  <!-- end of demo-second --> 
</div> <!-- end of 1 -->

<dv id="2">
  <div id="demo-second-dynamic">
    <div class="plainmodal-close-second"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div> <!-- end of plainmodal-close -->
    <h3 class="title">Thank you for subscribing!</h3>
    <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </br>
      </br>
      <hr id="line-break">
      </br>
      </br>
 </div>  <!-- end of demo-second -->
```

**jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropogation();

$('#mc-embedded-subscribe').on('click',function(){
if($('#1').css('display')!='none'){
$('#2').show().siblings('div').hide();
}else if($('#2').css('display')!='none'){
    $('#1').show().siblings('div').hide();
}
$('#1').hide(0,function(){
$('#2').show();
}

});
```

**css**

```
    #demo-second {
      width: 1024px;
      padding: 20px 40px;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 10px;
      display: none;
      font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica;
    }
    #demo-second:after { /* clearfix */
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: block;
    }

    #demo-second-dynamic {
      width: 1024px;
      padding: 20px 40px;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 10px;
      display: none;
      font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica;
    }
    #demo-second-dynamic:after { /* clearfix */
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: block;
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't stopping the form from submitting, so it will redirect the page before it executes your code.

```
$('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropogation();
    /* send form data here */
```

you can use the jquery.post() to send the form. Then check the result, then i would do something along the lines of

```
$('#1').hide(0,function(){
    $('#2').show();
}
```

EDIT:

Because you have `target="_blank"` in your form tag you don't need the first part of my answer, you can replace your whole "jquery" section with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').on('submit',function(){
    $('#1').hide(function(){$('#2').show();});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please provide exactly how I need to set up the code to make it work please? I'm not sure where to paste the code you've entered.

Also do you know if I should remove the custom URL for "thank you" page on MailChimp? It's currently set to the homepage.

Comment: I have now removed the "here is my dynamic content". I have also updated my post with the extra code you submitted, could you please check if that code has the right structure or if I am missing out on something?


The newsletter works fine, but still I get redirected to the homepage, can't find out what I am doing wrong here.